# How to calculate how many times a function is inside another function, for example g(9) inside g(k)

Tags: c, function

I am performing an activity, which is based on the recursive function, but I cannot understand how to put a part in code format. The code is this :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int count;
 int g( int x ) {
   count++;

   if ( x == 0 )
       return 2;

   if ( x <= 2 )
       return x * x;

   if ( x <= 5 )
       return x * g( x - 1 );

   return (g( x - 3 ) + g( x - 2 ) );
}

int main () {

  int k = 15;// random number
  count = 0;
    
  printf( " g(%d) = %d\n", k, g( k ) );
  printf( " count: %d\n", count);
  printf( " g(9) appeared : %d time(s) inside g(%d)",...,k);// in this space would be the other variable 

  return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is how to calculate how many times, for example g(9), appears inside g(k). I've already made some attempts, but it never arrives at what is really requested. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you asking how to keep a count of how many times g() is called with a given argument, or just how many times g() is called (possibly excluding the initial call)?  Either way, the most straightforward answer will work basically the same, with a global variable that is incremented every time the given criterion is met.  Your count variable within g() is useless unless it's declared static (though even then, main() won't be able to see it).

Comment: about what I'm really asking, is this first case that you talked about and I understood what you talked about using the global variable (like I put in the count), but I don't know how to do this with another variable in relation to this specific case (that of finding how many g(9) are inside for example g(27) ) according to those functions. Could you demonstrate me in code style? please, if you can. Sorry for being a little slow, I started to see about programming a few days ago.

Comment: If you have new information like clarification of your question, please [edit] your question. Here in the comments it will most likely be overlooked. If necessary, please take the [tour] again or read "[ask]" once more. -- As a note, is is not a good idea to communicate a solution in code. You need to learn to think in concepts and algorithms to become a developer. -- However, you can add an `if (x == 9)` if you are interested just in calls of `g(9)`, or you can provide an array of counters.